# No such column when column exists

Tags: sqlite, errors

I have a table (`trackedinfo`) inside my database that has the following columns (columns obtained by running `PRAGMA table_info(trackedinfo);`)

[image: columns of the table]

The problem is that even though the column `sendok` exists, when running a query on the database with that field, it throws an error.

**Example queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM trackedinfo WHERE sendok IS NULL;
SELECT sendok FROM trackedinfo;
```

**Error:**

```
SQLITE_ERROR: SQL error or missing database (no such column: sendok)
```

[image: error]

But, if I run a query selecting all of the fields, it brings me the info regarding `sendok`:

[image]

Here is the `CREATE` command of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE trackedinfo
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date_time_start TEXT,
    date_time_end TEXT,
    tracked_name TEXT,
    tracked_origin TEXT,
    tracked_maker TEXT,
    tracked_version TEXT,
    tracked_type TEXT,
    sendok TEXT,
    tracked_id TEXT
);
```

It also happens with the column `tracked_id`

Info that I got by executing `.schema trackedinfo`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "trackedinfo" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "date_time_start" TEXT, "date_time_end" TEXT, "tracked_name" TEXT, "tracked_origin" TEXT, "tracked_maker" TEXT, "tracked_version" TEXT, "tracked_type" TEXT, "sendok " TEXT, "tracked_id " TEXT);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I had an space at the end of the name of the columns, solved the problem by deleting such spaces.

**Before:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "trackedinfo" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
"date_time_start" TEXT, 
"date_time_end" TEXT, 
"tracked_name" TEXT, 
"tracked_origin" TEXT, 
"tracked_maker" TEXT, 
"tracked_version" TEXT, 
"tracked_type" TEXT, 
"sendok " TEXT, 
"tracked_id " TEXT);
```

**After:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "trackedinfo" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
"date_time_start" TEXT, 
"date_time_end" TEXT, 
"tracked_name" TEXT, 
"tracked_origin" TEXT, 
"tracked_maker" TEXT, 
"tracked_version" TEXT, 
"tracked_type" TEXT, 
"sendok" TEXT, 
"tracked_id" TEXT);
```

In the above examples white spaces within the **"sendok"** and "**tracked_id**" column names have been removed.

Comment: You should avoid quoting identifiers. If you do, you will have to do it everywhere in a consequent matter. `CREATE TABLE "Ape"...` are different from `CREATE TABLE "APe"...`, whereas `CREATE TABLE Ape...` is the same as `CREATE TABLE APe...` As you have already noticed, whitespace within quotes matters as well.